What are the benefits of using SPI CPHA=0?
There are two issues I see in CPHA=0 not present in CPHA=1,

Transmitter has to stabilize data sent before the first sampling edge
An extraneous release edge is done at the end to bring back SCK to its idle position

This mixes responsibilities of clocking and enabling to CS.
I prefer CPHA=1, but since the most common SPI mode is 0, CPOL=CPHA=0, I want to know other benefits of using this scheme.

Why is this important to you, the world will not remove these modes, and you could use whatever you see fit. What are your usual use cases, for example?

However, you might stumble across use cases where CPHA=1 is "better" (whatever that means to you) for the application (leaving your comfort zone), and you will be happy to have it.

Yes, these modes aren't going anywhere. I know that for the microcontroller space it's all abstracted away so all these different modes don't really matter but in hardware design this is a complication only coming up because of its popularity. That is why I'm asking if there are reasons besides its widespread use that we still use it.

As many systems use different notation, you mean the SPI PHA of which system?

If this is about why would any two chips communicate with SPI system where the first data bit needs to be present on the SPI data wire stably before the first clock, the reason is that the first bit and the data wire can be used as a handshake.
For example if there is no other handshake, a SPI master cannot know if SPI slave has data ready for it, without polling by clocking out a full byte.
However, in this mode, the SPI slave can set a byte to be transmitted that has the first bit in a state it want to indicate it has data to send, and that bit ends up directly to the IO pin, and the master may simply read the IO pin or generate an interrupt to know that the slave needs attention, and then transfer out the byte or packet that defines the status or data that is now readable.
In all cases the data needs to be set before the sampling edge defined by the clock polarity and phase. The set-up edge may be non-existent.
